# Mouse over on iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

The code is supposed to display a summary taken from an array when the user mouses over an inline frame. Typos happen to me all the time, but if the code itself isn't correct I would like to know why.

```
function setupFrame() {
    var allAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("area");
    for (i=0;i<allAreas.length;i++){
        allAreas[i].index = [i];
        allAreas[i].onmouseover = writeFrame();
        allAreas[i].onmouseout = clearFrame();
    }
}

function writeFrame() {
    var areaIndex = this.index;
    var frameWin = document.getElementById("parts");
    var frameDoc = frameWin.contentWindow.document;
    frameDoc.getElementById("docTitle").innerHTML = title[areaIndex].value;
    frameDoc.getElementById("docSummary").innerHTML = summary[areaIndex].value;
}

function clearFrame() {
    var areaIndex = this.index;
    var frameWin = document.getElementById("parts");
    var frameDoc = frameWin.contentWindow.document;
    frameDoc.getElementById("docTitle").innerHTML = "";
    frameDoc.getElementById("docSummary").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Why not use a debugger? Press `F12` and spend some time learning debug tools of your browser. It would certainly worth your time.